# Web Icons for Open Source Project

Tags: html, css, image, user-interface

I am working on a site, and I am looking for basic profile icons such as:

http://akcdn.okccdn.com/media/img/icons/home_new_user_guide.png

I would use those, but I am sure those are typewritten.

Where would I be able to find similar icons that I can use for an open source project?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Smashing Magazine](http://smashingmagazine.com) has semi-regular free icon roundups, including icons in a wide variety of styles. They're also under a wide variety of licenses, so make sure you check before using one.

Answer (score 2):

[FindIcons](http://findicons.com/) is a great site where you can find all icons that you need in almost any format and any size (may vary). And you can sort search results by color, icon style, license etc. enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

[iconfinder.net](http://iconfinder.net) is my go-to.  It's been around forever.